# "Permission denied" when run "ssh-copy-id node2"

Tags: ssh, hostname

I'm using ubuntu 20.04, in the file etc/hostnames, I wrote "192.168.1.1 node2" (node 2 is hostname of another node), then I want to ssh to node2. After I run *ssh-keygen*, I run *ssh-copy-id node2* and then the computer required to enter password, I entered node2 password but computer said "permission denied". But when I run ssh-copy-id node2@192.168.1.1, I can ssh to node2. Why I could not ssh to node 2 by command *ssh-copy-id node2* although I configured file etc/hostnames, I also reboot and run as root. May I configured wrong? Please explain me, thanks a lot!

Comment: `node2` in `/etc/hosts` (I hope you didn't trash `/etc/hostnames`) associates s. IP address with a hostname. Your use of `ssh-copy-id` is suboptimal, read `man ssh-copy-id`

Comment: "permission denied" type of problems usualy come from permission on destination machine. did you check the right and permission on the $HOME/.ssh  directory and files ? (usualy is 0600) alos the distant $HOME must not be world writable.

Comment: You seem to be confused about which part of the command refers to the hostname, and which to the username. When you use `ssh-copy-id node2`, it will attempt to copy the id to a user account with the same name as your current local user, whereas `ssh-copy-id node2@192.168.1.1` will attempt to copy it to an account with the username `node2`

Comment: I had mistake at hostname and username, but the main problem I'm confusing is how can I copy ssh of node2, ip 192.168.1.1 by command "ssh-copy-id node2"